# When writing names for .mp3 and .pdf files (songs, books etc.) in Windows, do you use hyphen, en or em dash to separate an author and his/her work?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, capitalization, computing

When writing names for .mp3 and .pdf files (songs, books etc.) in Windows, do you use hyphen, en or em dash to separate an author and his/her work?

Ex.

"Linkin Park - In the End" or "Linkin Park – In the End" or "Linkin Park — In the End"

"Edgar Allan Poe - The Black Cat" "Edgar Allan Poe – The Black Cat" "Edgar Allan Poe — The Black Cat"

Also, do you put a space between a hyphen/dash and two words?

Ex.

"Vanessa Mae—Storm" or "Vanessa Mae — Storm"

Comment: This is not about the English language at all. There is no ‘right’ or ‘wrong’ way to do this. You can choose to do it any way you want—they’re your files, after all.

Answer (score 1):

M-dashes may be problematic in file names, it's best to avoid non-ascii characters, particularly if you're sharing them to other systems.

As someone who does a lot of command line file munging, I wouldn't use spaces with the dashes between author and title. That way you can split the file name at the dash and get the separate bits without any trailing or leading spaces. But you may not be planning on doing anything of the sort, so do what pleases you.